# How do you restrict a property and template literal variable to the same value?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

It's easier to show what I'm asking for than to title this post:

```
type Foo = "bar" | "baz";

interface Consistency {
    foo: Foo;
    fooTemplate: `${Foo} in a template`;
}

// I want this to compile (and it does)
const valid1: Consistency = {
    foo: "bar",
    fooTemplate: "bar in a template",
}

const valid2: Consistency = {
    foo: "baz",
    fooTemplate: "baz in a template",
}

// I DON'T want this to compile (and it does)
const invalid1: Consistency = {
    foo: "bar",
    fooTemplate: "baz in a template",
}

const invalid2: Consistency = {
    foo: "baz",
    fooTemplate: "bar in a template",
}
```

[You can play with this example here.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKAiARgQwE6qgHzSwC9UBuAKAoEsA7YCbAM0wGNoBhOWgZ2p4a1WIKAG8KUSVCYIAXLASUp0hABUIAWzAAbTA3kADACSj4cAL5Q6UTFAZbdDA5XNUA9G6gBJKAHdM9HYAFvx2iKxwWtTa0AAUAQAmVsBQCXAQPACUFBG8KQBumNrUCQCM8ly8-ILCyGISUjJw8hg4qAA0DZJN6g56EC1Y2Fa0NnaaOv0dFK453AJQhcUJAEwV89UQQiIo4spNg5iknftqE44DREcjY-aTDNOzHt5QACIA8gByAOSqfgEpYAhHhhKARKIxKDxWhJagpNIZbK5BZ0JYlcpQSp8ARbWq7LoqZpXXAnRpnPr6K7EG62O4XR5UZEpVFFEprTEbHHbOp7MlE1rHAk9c79Q7Day0kUPTrmIA) I tried changing `Consistency` to

```
interface Consistency {
    foo: Foo;
    fooTemplate: `${foo} in a template`; //lowercase foo
}
```

but that doesn't compile. Is it possible to have the compiler error in the invalid cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapped type and directly unpack it to get a union type of all valid sub-types:

```
type Consistency  = {
    [K in Foo]: {
        foo: K;
        fooTemplate: `${K} in a template`;
    }
}[Foo]
```

Comment: Weird. I get that except for the `[Foo]` at the end.  Where can I learn about this concept?

Comment: Without the `[Foo]`, you create an object like `{ bar: { foo: "bar", fooTemplate: "bar in a template"}, baz: { foo: "baz", fooTemplate: "baz in a template"}  }` The `[Foo]` could also be written as `[ "bar" | "baz" ]` and selects the value types of these two properties from that object. That way you get the union type out of it.
No idea where I got that from though ^^

Comment: Oh, that's a good explanation.  Using `[K]` makes more sense to me, but I guess that's out of scope?

Comment: Yes, also K would be one individual value and in this position you explicitly want it to be the union of all possible values.